# How to redirect a register user from domain.com to app.domain.com with React and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I built two apps
domain.com - A landing page + a sign in and a signup form.
app.domain.com - The app itself.

After the user is logging in I redirect him to app.domain.com using window.location

But I don't succeed to build something that will do:

1. Check if user has a FBtoken
2. redirect user to app.domain.com
3. store the token in app.domain.com
4. Get user from firebase
5. If there is such user show the app, if not redirect back to domain.com

Here is The App component of the Domain.com:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from './../UserProvider'
import { Router } from '@reach/router'

import Homepage from './Homepage'
import Signup from './Signup'
import Login from './Login'
import PasswordReset from './PasswordReset'

function Application() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext)   
  return user ? (
    <a href='http://app.domain.com/'>Go to app</a>
  ) : (
    <Router>
      <Signup path='signUp' />
      <Login path='signIn' />
      <PasswordReset path='passwordReset' />
      <Homepage path='/' />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Application
```

I guess that I need to use the cookies to store the FBtoken and not the local storage...
However, I read that Firebase automatically sends a new session tokan every hour so how I implement that with cookies?

I didn't add the app.domain.com code because It too long and I don't know exactly what to provide (contextProvider? App component? )
Please let me know and I will add anything that is necessary

Thanks for the helpers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for session cookies, which give you more control over the life cycle and other aspects of the authentication session. The general flow for this is:

1. The user signs in with a regular Firebase Authentication provider.
2. Your application code sends the user's ID token to a custom end point you make (on a server you control or in Cloud Functions).
3. In this end point you verify the ID token, and mint a session cookie from it.
4. The client then signs out from its previous authentication session, and uses the session cookie to authenticate.

For full information on this see the Firebase documentation on [session cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies) and this blog post [Firebase: Introducing session cookies for server-side web apps](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/firebase-introducing-session-cookies-for-server-side-web-apps-fb46cce40b2).

Comment: Its seems that the article you attached is for server-side web apps. Will that be good in my case as well?

Comment: It requires server-side code in step 2 and 3, but step 1 and 4 are client-side. You can't mint a token/session cookie securely on a client, as that would mean any client could mint whatever tokens/session cookies they want.

Comment: Unfortunatally it didn't =(